# Key value database organization in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, key-value, entity-attribute-value

I have a user ruby on rails model with username, password fields. I want to add edit profile form something like on that image

[image link](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/6634/zx0d.png)

Any field should have an extra sharebox(boolean) either or not user wants to share his profile information based on field.

What is the best way of organizing this kind of model? Ideally this should be key-value like table for storing each field information individiually. Something like

key, value, share?

```
Firstname, John, true
Lastname, Smith, true
Gender, male, false
Brithday, 19.01.1985, true
```

What is the best way of organizing this kind of model structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like: "Should i use an EAV?"

You should look here for a good forum discussion on this subject: 
http://www.dbforums.com/database-concepts-design/1619660-otlt-eav-design-why-do-people-hate.html

Most of the time i guess the answer is no (just google "SQL antipatterns EAV" to a bunch of resources on the subject). Why don't use a plain table with all the fields? Is there this many attributes? You can also store the data inside a Blob column if the fields aren't constants (to avoid EAV).

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with EAV structure:

- You lose the ability to use SQL data types (every value must be TEXT).
- You lose the ability to use SQL constraints like UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY or even NOT NULL.
- You lose the ability to query a row of data as one row, without writing a huge query that does a self-join as many times as you have attributes.
- Storing the "key" or attribute name *every* time you use it is very wasteful.

Is that enough?

Read this article about a company that almost shut down because someone thought this would be a "universal" way to store data: [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/).

I have discussed [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) a lot on StackOverflow, and in my blog article [EAV FAIL](https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/), and in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

The better solution for a *relational* database is to define one column per attribute.

- You can give columns meaningful names, and this is stored once as metadata, instead of on every row.
- You can use appropriate SQL data types to help enforce proper data validation.
- You can use SQL constraints also to help data integrity. Otherwise you have to implement data rules by writing lots of code in your app, and I hope you have better things to do.